# The stage in which the data for the instruction is fetched from memory or cache

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

I cannot find any official (detailed) information about instruction cycle or instruction pipelining in modern CPU's (especially for AMD Zen+ and newer).

Consider the following instruction:

```
ADD MEM, REG
```

In which stage the data for the [mem] operand is fetched from memory? Before (decoding) or in execution stage?

Comment: How could it get decoded if it hasn't even been fetched from I-cache?  Fetch is always the first stage in any pipeline.  See https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/ (unfortunately David Kanter hasn't done a Zen deep-dive, but a Zen has only a few really major qualitative differences from Haswell.  They both have a uop cache.)  https://www.realworldtech.com/bulldozer/ is his most recent AMD deep dive, about Bulldozer which suffers from a few design decisions that turned out not to work well.  See also https://agner.org/optimize/ for Agner Fog's microarch guide: that covers Zen.

Comment: Or do you mean the data for the `[mem]` operand, that gets fed to the ALU, rather than the machine code?  The operand data is fetched by a separate load uop.  memory-source ALU instructions decode to load / ALU / store uops.  See Agner Fog's guide, and http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/

Comment: Yes, i mean the data for the [mem] operand.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for excellent articles.
So, it's execution stage? Do i understand correctyly, that:
- FETCH/DECODE/EXECUTE stages aren't atomic, and each stage is built from several μops?
- ALU operates on already fetched from memory or register values?
- computation of memory address of operand is performed by AGU in EXECUTE stage?
- memory address computation and fetching operand value from memory can be performed in parallel to other instructions in pipeline (
superscalar processor) if those instructions are independed of each other?

Comment: Stages aren't "built from" uops.  A modern out-of-order exec CPU isn't one linear pipeline.  The memory operand is loaded at execution of a separate uop, before the `add` uop can execute.  Remember that modern CPUs do *out-of-order* exec, so it's not just a memory stage *before* the ALU stage (like in-order Atom did, IIRC).  Running `add [mem], eax` is very similar to running 3 separate instructions `mov tmpreg, [mem]` / `add tmpreg, eax` / `mov [mem], tmpreg`, likely actually using a hidden internal register that's renamed like the architectural registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Modern Microprocessors A 90-Minute Guide!](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/)

> (...) **dynamically decode the x86 instructions into simple, RISC-like micro-instructions, which can then be executed by a fast, RISC-style register-renaming OOO superscalar core.** (...) Most x86 instructions decode into 1, 2 or 3 μops, while the more complex instructions require a larger number.

OOO (out-of-order execution), means:

> **processor executes instructions in an order governed by the
> availability of input data and execution units, rather than by their
> original order in a program**. In doing so, the processor can avoid
> being idle while waiting for the preceding instruction to complete and
> can, in the meantime, process the next instructions that are able to
> run immediately and independently.

source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution)

1. Original CISC instruction is decoded into RISC-like μops.
2. Modern CPU's are superpipelined-[superscalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor) causes instruction level parallelism which means single core is able to execute multiple instructions in parallel (and multiple instructions per clock cycle).
3. Because data dependecies the order of execution isn't arbitrary, on the presented example (`add [mem], eax`), ALU part (μop) cannot be executed completely before the the value of `[mem]` is fetched.
4. "**The memory operand is loaded at execution of a separate μop, before the add μop can execute.**", just like @peter-cordes said.

Comment: Good summary.  I only commented instead of posting an answer because I didn't know where to start / what level of detail of explanation would be appropriate.  (And because more-detailed explanations already exist.)  But this is good, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Like said in the comments usually the instruction needs to be decoded first before fetching the data from memory.
However, in modern cpu the DCU try to predict the data that you gonna use and pre-fetch it before even the instruction has being decoded. This is usually true for accessing array or well known patterns.

Comment: That's prefetching *into cache*, not into the core proper (load execution unit, bypass forwarding network, etc.)  The closes HW prefetch will ever bring your data is L1d cache.  (But yes, L1d prefetch in modern Intel CPUs does look at addresses used in actual load instructions, not just patterns of cache misses.)

Comment: Completely true. I just thought that the question was when the data is fetched from main memory into the CPU (after all L1d cache is inside the core).

Comment: Ah I see.  I think from context (discussion of instruction-fetch vs. execute stage) it was talking about pulling data into the pipeline proper.  Also note the title said "fetched from memory or cache".  Anyway, I see how the question could be misinterpreted.